# How Do I Add DriveInfoEx.Dll In Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have go through [Serial number of Hard Disk or Hard Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675761/serial-number-of-hard-disk-or-hard-drive).

And Found the information about `DriveInfoEx.Dll` but don't know how to reference it as I don't know actual path of it?.I have tried it by add reference but I haven't found it from `.Net` & `Com tab` of `Add Reference`.

Can any one guide me how to add `DriveInfoEx.Dll` in `c# win application` project?.

Is it System `.dll` Or User create .dll?.

Comment: Did you try anything? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] also..

Comment: Do you know the location of the DLL?

Comment: @SonerGönül, I have no idea or information about DriveInfoEx.Dll?. Even don't know what is DriveInfoEx.Dll and where is it in system?. don't know about it's address in system so how can I provide you more information about it?. can u tell me please.

Comment: If you don't know what or where it is, why do you want to use it? 
If you just don't know where it is, download it from the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: Go to the [page of the project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16941/Get-Physical-HDD-Serial-Number-without-WMI), which implements the DLL 
Then download the demo project (you need an account to do that), after you downloaded the archive, extract the content (or the DLL only).
Right click on `References` --> `Add New Reference…`, `Browse`, then search for the DLL and reference it with a double click or click on open.
Mark the DLL (Namespace) in the Reference folder and set `Local Copy` to `True`.
This will make sure the DLL is always in the same folder as the executable file. 
To use the DLL in your code import the namespace via `using XYZ.XYZ;`

Comment: Janes Abou Chleih, Please see my new edit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a Dll that is not listed in the Add Reference dialog, just click the browse button in that dialog and then find the Dll in the open dialog window. You will need to do this in the correct section for the Dll (i.e., the .NET tab for .NET Dlls).